# How to avoid that the user can close the editor window in a RCP-eclipse-plugin programmatically?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

How to do away the "X" at the editor window of a RCP-eclipse-plugin and avoid that the user can close the editor programmatically?

Would it be possible and if so how?

Comment: Getting rid of the X is very hard.

Comment: @greg-449: But is it possible? Or is it possible to disable closing the editor in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an Eclipse e4 application you can just uncheck the 'closeable' option in the part design.

For a 3.x compatibility mode RCP you can't use the closeable option. One way to make the part uncloseable would be to use a [custom renderer](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Renderer/article.html) to override the part stack renderer `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer` and override the `isCloseable` method:

```java
public class MyStackRenderer extends StackRenderer
{
  @Override
  protected boolean isClosable(final MPart part)
  {
    if (part.getObject() instanceof MyEditor) {
      return false;
    }

    return super.isClosable(part);
  }
}
```

where `MyEditor` is your editor class.

This require Eclipse 4 but can be used with 3.x compatibility mode RCPs.

Comment: `public class EditorUnclosableRenderer extends StackRenderer {

    @Override
    protected boolean isClosable(final MPart part) {
        if (part.getObject() instanceof BDDEditor) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
        // return super.isClosable(part);
    }
}`

Comment: just return `false` at the `isClosable`-method, this works for me.